Wordpress Gravity Forms Issue with Form Submission
I have a WordPress site which uses gravity forms. On a listing page, I am able to submit an inquiry form for the product in question.
However, I am sometimes met with an error message saying "There was a problem with your submission. Please Review the fields below.". I am also sometimes met with an additional error message saying "The reCAPTCHA was invalid. Go back and try it again.".
I have an automated email flow using Zapier and Mailgun that happens after the form is submitted to notify the owner of a lead. The issue is that even if the form throws one of the two errors mentioned above the form submission and email flow still go through and get sent.
I am more concerned about giving the user a more pleasant experience so that they always know the form was submitted properly.
Problem with your submission & reCAPTCHA issue:


Confirm the settings are correct in Google Captcha including API keys. You may want to switch to hCaptcha

I asked Gravity Forms support and they said the following:
"There are a couple of potential causes of this issue, so we'll start with a couple of the most common and see if we need to go further.
First, caching is known to cause issues with form submissions. For that reason, we recommend excluding your form page URLs from caching so that visitors always get a fresh version of the form/page. I'm not familiar with Convesio Caching, so I recommend checking with their team to find out exactly how to exclude a URL from the cache. After you've added the exclusion, purge the cache, then test the form from a private/incognito window to see if the issue persists.
Another thing to check for is the reCAPTCHA field, which should not be part of the form when you're using the reCAPTCHA add-on. I know that's a little confusing! reCAPTCHA V2 is built into Gravity Forms and requries the reCAPTCHA field. V3 requires the add-on and does not require adding the field to your forms. If you have the reCAPTCHA field, that could cause false validation errors.
Check on those and let us know what you find out, then we'll go from there if those changes don't resolve the issue."
In my case I had reCAPTCHA in the form and I had the reCAPTCHA add-on. After I removed the reCAPTCHA field from the form I was using I stopped receiving errors and consistently received the thank you message that appears afterward.

